# zend framework 2 apigility assets not loading

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm new to Zend Framework, and having spent a couple of days getting to grips with some basics, I decided to add `Apigility`. 
`Apigility` and `apigility-admin` installed as expected using composer, but when i go to `/apigility/ui`, the page loads, but doesn't load the referenced assets (js images, css etc.) - none are found. 
They are in the assets folder of the module.

My searches have drawn a blank.

Any advice how to investigate this further?

Comment: What assets are showing when the page loads? Your main template by some chance?

Comment: I had a similar issue when I first started, I resolved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676164/zf2-apigility-installed-in-my-own-app-route-not-working?rq=1 In subsequent installations of ApiGility, I did not have to do this as I used a different setup.